# How to set keyboard's alpha in ios 8

Tags: ios

I am coding with ios8's keyboard extension, when I used the following code it doesn't work well, can anyone help me?

```
   self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() //it became gray
   self.view.alpha = 0.1 //it made all the view on keyboard become transparent
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work well" ?

Comment: all the view on keyboard becamed transparency,i only want to let the back ground transparenty and i view draw uiview on it